# NFS Debian Jessie server and client

Tags: debian, mount, nfs, fstab

I am trying to find the correct syntax for mounting a file share of nfs.
On the host I have the `/etc/export` file set like so: `/mnt/externalHD 192.168.0.8(ro,sync)` and the client fstab like so: `192.168.0.2/mnt/externalHD /home/Plex nfs auto 0 0`
I have also installed `nfs-common` and `nfs-kernel-server` but have had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `/etc/fstab` file you are missing a ":", it should be:

```
192.168.0.2:/mnt/externalHD /home/Plex nfs ro,sync 0 0
```

[19.2.1. Mounting NFS File Systems using /etc/fstab](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-nfs-fstab.html)

The file is also `/etc/exports` and not `/etc/export`. You should start/restart the nfs service after changing `/etc/exports`.

I will also leave the link about the exports file:

[21.7. The /etc/exports Configuration File](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-nfs-server-config-exports.html)

As for the actual mount point in the client, it has to exist. Do:

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/Plex
```

Comment: That didn't work. It's not mounted on the client

Comment: I have changed the fstab line

Comment: I get this message: `mount.nfs: mount point /home/Plex does not exist`

Comment: It is a good sign. do a `sudo mkdir -p /home/Plex ` and then `sudo mount -a`

Comment: I had to do a `systemctl enable nfs-kernel-server ` it now shows that it's exported. However on the client it will not mount in the fstab as I get     `mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.`
`mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.`
`mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified`

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: have you installed the nfs client?

Answer (score 2):

I had to `sudo systemctl enable rpcbind` then do a `sudo mount -a` this solved it

Comment: Do you solved your problem?

Comment: I cannot vote for my own post